# Error in pts when when calling function ordiellipse in VEGAN package: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, vegan

I have a nice DCA ordination of some of my data, but can't produce an ordiellipse for all different dataclusters. My data is found in the bottom of this post.

What happens now: I have four different groups (Block A-D) with three clusters per group (three year categories). So, I want to end up with  different delineated groups. When I run the `ordiellipes` I get the following error message:

```
Error in pts[gr, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
    In addition: Warning message:
    In complete.cases(pts) & !is.na(groups) :
      longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and a graph as follows:
[DCA ordination of four blocks of vegetation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96RTc.png)

This piece of code reproduces the error, but due to the reduced dataset presented here, the graph looks a bit different:

```
install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)

{plot(site_scr_kikker, type="n", main="Kikkervalleien", xlab="DCA1 Eigenvalue = 0.62",
          ylab="DCA2 Eigenvalue = 0.39")
points(site_scr_kikker, display = "sites", cex = 0.8, pch=10)
 ordiellipse(site_scr_kikker, Years_KIKKER, kind="se", conf=0.95, lwd=2,
                 draw = "polygon", col=1:4, border=1:4,
                 alpha=63)}
```

DCA Axes Dataset:

```
structure(list(DCA1 = c(-0.554410061801955, 2.68272013411215, 
2.68697635940812, 2.82668169800565, 2.80053527027075, 2.23642581481516, 
2.35425133786973, 2.52415368531054, 2.83239838572004, 2.84069370354046, 
2.77338234239721, 2.81710120200121, 3.02325331285456, 2.53697043507954, 
3.05037536310673, 3.32304086730676, 2.94495328416423, 3.15022598269494, 
3.39489992455406, 3.28769160043834, -0.350924337608413, 0.275699505382009, 
0.297344502163647, 0.240762119868438, 0.228861788615913, 0.314964666243383, 
0.371085287846039, 0.455145784364889, 0.652221371003541, 0.499839296442089, 
0.379360398080226, 0.549933370572594, 0.399966004306952, 0.500218697886041, 
0.441564088620194, 0.374702692230443, 0.382333410536051, 0.43285459912782, 
0.428611459750847, 0.349092514843647, -0.888853907037661, -1.28333663263808, 
-1.40792331844972, -1.38537198615101, -1.38995889090796, -1.3655773745443, 
-1.31803656153966, -1.34826448701426, -1.34653537792753, -1.49305269877646, 
-1.50814236008689, -1.41827597394111, -1.39602666811321, -1.4148816003514, 
-1.49783699791751, -1.47003691605731, -1.42755467648435, -1.30533485632748, 
-1.36950094020217, -1.23477912087743, 3.23114892464093, 2.9350886798946, 
3.14124836945073, 3.26161277365282, 3.09515391638416, 3.1529521123077, 
3.06459587965894, 3.10368520711438, 3.22697584876561, 3.53654928835111, 
2.98450087615265, 3.270797532973, 3.26776719866589, 3.49199289032157, 
3.22923990263853, 3.25429242878212, 3.04740856725947, 3.0826704683258, 
3.13214804334072, 3.02742007198209, -0.117264033632094, -0.16440126600505, 
-0.0448538849517754, -0.0426633870391433, 0.0330104299718532, 
-0.0752808949299411, 0.117242046915944, 0.0416044435035445, 0.124146770645119, 
0.0523946356429974, -0.110261999817611, -0.228252641183511, -0.188814210123203, 
-0.290927018876809, -0.248633979863795, -0.0903889717097015, 
-0.123459222045697, -0.149699086185127, -0.150112841061331, 3.01689076683526, 
2.01577708020474, 2.03044077034707, 2.07207139315213, 2.12441461917371, 
2.03701011931199, 2.01252790874418, 1.83219506720427, 2.04345013029757, 
2.15504917885961, 2.06913115663176, 1.98989149024749, 1.99123174245595, 
1.96507730677135, 1.95295285738276, 2.04095710166195, 1.84679490913208, 
1.83479477688629, 2.06370280057877, 2.09660967186289, 0.541840589690319, 
0.103220405988339, 0.145850580989204, 0.171702980416538, 0.0991444115624873, 
0.163980634495489, 0.0100630096884953, 0.00653099371627297, -0.049057450717042, 
-0.0731989798652191, 0.0484957737765508, -0.0813429375561661, 
0.226394829075491, 0.118747426326434, 0.0785696207929674, 0.372080921641888, 
0.228084973201013, 0.436449500065551, 0.380195760092951, 0.421054280535058, 
-0.3407891239866, -0.770535673192646, -0.78726979249955, -0.605034153126869, 
-0.79603463000109, -0.611191548761836, -0.479087063427777, -0.431712806416684, 
-0.442179135680639, -0.359040655364315, -0.387751952086651, -0.333064178275891, 
-0.245245634230479, -0.294664916205089, -0.325293571885643, -0.371714350289459, 
-0.384076243072539, -0.364275416660051, -0.492176029276133, -0.360665042070641, 
1.97498200909125, 1.71918456504906, 1.65998788992634, 1.66434225634425, 
1.56633028293729, 1.74620235786651, 1.62590128379407, 1.50258825353478, 
1.48820880624004, 1.42926003809109, 1.45513337793396, 1.42592371006012, 
1.4963606424124, 1.44021703608174, 1.44438380462437, 1.47109090679392, 
1.82139520526838, 1.43656718298432, 1.44873704214624, 1.6139306940386, 
0.329534864476447, 0.242211052748716, 0.235001084932526, 0.203151203202996, 
0.0621389966258401, 0.0944651233344451, 0.335947463398379, 0.34920131294113, 
0.356337550057783, 0.413800173211847, 0.475501084593146, 0.636972497835927, 
0.378416570342712, 0.405927373162309, 0.483958766985421, 0.313492417628128, 
0.18082570013463, 0.213448692873988, 0.175969392011173, 0.306174433718341, 
-0.661344430804266, -0.36312534912334, -0.531638029637394, -0.323308841681458, 
-0.1705480775506, -0.320797820641974, -0.0112455616689928, 0.0058094693123143, 
-0.173103348877858, -0.187484910613069, -0.140328782633759, -0.262935718115112, 
-0.213706195115846, -0.201623466852359, -0.176562229774177, -0.129977719792298, 
-0.214157064357283, -0.312304712680445, -0.321801942265119, -0.447307072541585
), DCA2 = c(1.55135681949654, 0.390676820301294, 0.298911889220322, 
0.263998071977169, 0.318540344211798, 0.261720092088233, 0.185092505227324, 
0.266125079431566, 0.394828240097056, 0.302396200887096, 0.427178178571868, 
0.362329582087479, 0.329300702637127, 0.106852609024896, 0.0916401140801768, 
-0.0498768808296606, 0.0568755736541453, 0.0409183688588972, 
-0.00982842960758612, -0.0532614523308772, 2.37879922539826, 
0.870845236307184, 0.875448127097767, 0.641275864686684, 0.642137889278431, 
0.61287181240447, 0.46096369228661, 0.353139355245069, 0.30571197713629, 
0.127480232335107, 0.155591712070341, 0.201701485575426, 0.164465659451652, 
0.053079369473755, 0.0208974057538049, 0.146542798250278, 0.133527092556681, 
0.0558014251324042, 0.0947450033654067, 0.146527814538444, 1.5634624218799, 
-0.045338607959831, 0.0921067787998133, 0.100136516321785, 0.176555931155601, 
0.1779356816878, 0.169352553487154, 0.159084219879744, 0.1416643202517, 
0.046751076432749, -0.0143690327219694, 0.0854961342502074, 0.0502099136978105, 
0.0730195528098192, 0.0853374008019263, 0.115531044767214, 0.0847573955605063, 
0.163097640034325, 0.134198472975748, 0.275479651900967, 0.0460034929226141, 
0.560715956164233, 0.37831200537774, 0.258027386145382, 0.388149229049795, 
0.321257843490554, 0.403942482899889, 0.195339552141307, 0.151011302110764, 
0.0876417694236817, 0.0587161407304979, 0.0994546033680268, 0.251510488850064, 
0.122130974589908, 0.111911790245653, 0.165535261771949, 0.060970314956561, 
0.225723170237567, 0.313941078588394, 0.231918137883269, 0.993679773684799, 
0.881292795126892, 0.949549576326203, 0.820143650778247, 0.967230951435818, 
0.913507935790706, 0.987962294037885, 0.89747403569919, 1.0281502304616, 
1.03056849037379, 0.985558206829436, 0.956118614451869, 0.990861510942461, 
1.03853618229401, 0.76894643786781, 0.71956843396122, 0.895677149723554, 
1.04202078104011, 0.994362394242357, 0.45816044069548, -0.256799924265915, 
-0.219215409286906, -0.274974314031124, 0.00673120866587418, 
-0.34588695905374, -0.330796391785146, -0.284953089585678, -0.358994836114401, 
-0.0877152907820218, -0.0179836181616615, -0.0514356092538941, 
-0.0631722426274615, -0.321764014760995, -0.292880797095688, 
-0.124966216219314, 0.0448721698628494, -0.0122687592139075, 
-0.0293240055712474, 0.241689548511685, 0.258771228150735, -0.243978231909183, 
-0.273670301716394, -0.346381197575676, -0.540924824745573, -0.578466142473874, 
-0.881698449269004, -0.988487876600371, -0.874559759965791, -0.898043753863041, 
-0.65177624643986, -0.897172266653606, -0.428027378766614, -0.618350571130815, 
-0.650486911424929, -0.522529645458612, -0.540007295687359, -0.56048323820591, 
-0.318120499195913, -0.233107811772576, 1.11444300342379, -0.464311522843928, 
-0.671043500267456, -0.293709784912165, -0.48957037940714, -0.303799057505386, 
-0.5014139212286, -0.446968540045644, -0.584723850846212, -0.768962102318167, 
-0.473903387692755, -0.476071214131476, -0.738718937014587, -0.802748557174088, 
-0.878862063849493, -1.03232927446183, -0.901938937530595, -0.90685531694932, 
-0.835172924486567, -0.444400981243365, 0.0711913939922195, -0.376272209371, 
-0.278328148225639, -0.37229823300335, -0.158396017104884, -0.221206427389147, 
-0.356652754022269, -0.130851791393296, -0.208569352651987, -0.12330848067377, 
0.119039186900003, -0.145975049001435, -0.0110773787283525, 0.154455358806736, 
0.186221284305681, 0.0518734671667143, 0.0410707622863646, 0.295096579413462, 
0.277622386022512, -0.0377429837590535, -0.126848197591401, -0.0574585504960616, 
-0.250845634712495, -0.0177800130809138, -0.107737216176091, 
-0.0631643821637247, 0.1010605032824, -0.0442202733629364, -0.372070473916875, 
-0.533311401539873, -0.724584176353283, -0.865166680824871, -0.87656068793911, 
-0.813421991975295, -0.839998556813832, -0.655707249050569, -0.534597066763741, 
-0.378820955906015, -0.0722774697143169, -0.109467994974947, 
-0.331582307211823, -1.28959124402666, -1.37962362889618, -1.43451046953702, 
-1.38447488090246, -1.69236882979906, -1.44344360082209, -1.3915281556235, 
-1.58096147044615, -1.68132043125815, -2.20367091829309, -2.5599499288299, 
-2.31297384112025, -2.38435599310711, -2.20768782296035, -1.65607037944418, 
-1.64014952994504, -1.69013789782066, -1.7017681151936, -1.61898692370139
)), .Names = c("DCA1", "DCA2"), row.names = c("01A01", "01A02", 
"01A03", "01A04", "01A05", "01A06", "01A07", "01A08", "01A09", 
"01A10", "01A11", "01A12", "01A13", "01A14", "01A15", "01A16", 
"01A17", "01A18", "01A19", "01A20", "08A01", "08A02", "08A03", 
"08A04", "08A05", "08A06", "08A07", "08A08", "08A09", "08A10", 
"08A11", "08A12", "08A13", "08A14", "08A15", "08A16", "08A17", 
"08A18", "08A19", "08A20", "18A01", "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", 
"18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", 
"18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", 
"18A19", "18A20", "01B01", "01B02", "01B03", "01B04", "01B05", 
"01B06", "01B07", "01B08", "01B09", "01B10", "01B11", "01B12", 
"01B13", "01B14", "01B15", "01B16", "01B17", "01B18", "01B19", 
"01B20", "18B02", "18B03", "18B04", "18B05", "18B06", "18B07", 
"18B08", "18B09", "18B10", "18B11", "18B12", "18B13", "18B14", 
"18B15", "18B16", "18B17", "18B18", "18B19", "18B20", "01C01", 
"01C02", "01C03", "01C04", "01C05", "01C06", "01C07", "01C08", 
"01C09", "01C10", "01C11", "01C12", "01C13", "01C14", "01C15", 
"01C16", "01C17", "01C18", "01C19", "01C20", "08C01", "08C02", 
"08C03", "08C04", "08C05", "08C06", "08C07", "08C08", "08C09", 
"08C10", "08C11", "08C12", "08C13", "08C14", "08C15", "08C16", 
"08C17", "08C18", "08C19", "08C20", "18C01", "18C02", "18C03", 
"18C04", "18C05", "18C06", "18C07", "18C08", "18C09", "18C10", 
"18C11", "18C12", "18C13", "18C14", "18C15", "18C16", "18C17", 
"18C18", "18C19", "18C20", "01D01", "01D02", "01D03", "01D04", 
"01D05", "01D06", "01D07", "01D08", "01D09", "01D10", "01D11", 
"01D12", "01D13", "01D14", "01D15", "01D16", "01D17", "01D18", 
"01D19", "01D20", "08D01", "08D02", "08D03", "08D04", "08D05", 
"08D06", "08D07", "08D08", "08D09", "08D10", "08D11", "08D12", 
"08D13", "08D14", "08D15", "08D16", "08D17", "08D18", "08D19", 
"08D20", "18D01", "18D02", "18D03", "18D04", "18D05", "18D06", 
"18D07", "18D08", "18D09", "18D10", "18D11", "18D12", "18D13", 
"18D14", "18D15", "18D16", "18D17", "18D18", "18D19", "18D20"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Years_Kikker Dataset

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("2001_A", "2001_B", 
"2001_C", "2001_D", "2008_A", "2008_C", "2008_D", "2018_A", "2018_B", 
"2018_C", "2018_D"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Difficult to say, but at least your data sets have different dimensions: DCA ordination has 219 points, and Years have 220 observations. Try to make these two to match to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the reply. As usual, your suggestion worked. I did not look good enough at my dataframes. Thanks a lot! Baby steps, but I keep learning.